# scope of a variable inside of a nested loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am trying to read through an `ActiveStorage::Attached::One` object that is a txt file uploaded by the user.

Could anyone help me why the variable 'grid' inside the `line.chars.each_with_index` is nil?

```rb
txt_file = self.file.download.delete(' ')  # returns the content of the file as a string

txt_file.each_line.with_index do |line, row_index| 
  next line if row_index == 0

  if row_index == 1
    grid = self.grids.create(generation: 0, rows: line[0].to_i, cols: line[1].to_i)
  end

  line.chars.each_with_index do |cell, column_index|
    grid.cells.create(alive: cell == "*", row_position: row_index, column_position: column_index)
  end
end
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry I did not describe the context. We are inside a Model 'Game' that has_many 'Grid' and a 'Grid' has_many 'Cell'. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever `row_index` is not equal to `0` or equal to `1`, `grid` is not assigned and therefore evaluates to `nil`. In other words, whenever `txt_fle` has three lines or more, `grid` will be `nil` at some point.